dlib library is not installing even though i have cmake
I am running the code on IDLE.
This the error code:
× Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [11 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
        File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
        File "C:\Users\Shimb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\cmake.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'

      ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Failed to build dlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

i tried reinstalling cmake but nothing worked.

If you are running pip, do so from the command line.

i am already running on cmd

If you are running on cmd, you are not running on IDLE

"i tried reinstalling cmake but nothing worked." what steps did you take to do this? What happens when you take those steps?

so i installed cmake from the website. then added cmake to the path
